# Line graph plot in R with a line for a single data series changing color, i.e. 1 line, 2 colors

Tags: r, colors, plot, line

I would like to make a simple line plot like this:

```
things <- c(1, 3, 6, 4, 9)
plot(things, type="o", col="blue", axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
axis(1, at=1:5, lab=c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"))
axis(2, las=1)
box()
```

[(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuGrM.jpg)

BUT with the single line changing color at a certain data point, in this case, say, blue Monday-Wednesay, and red for Wednesday-Friday.  I.e. from the data point number 1 to 3, the line is blue, from 3 to 5, it would be red.

I know I can just split the data series into two, and plot them separately and the image will join them, but the real data I am using is from a large complex data frame, and I need to make the plot from dozens of them, so having one quick little code to do it without manipulating the actual data would be a big time-saver.

One line, two colors, that's it!

Thanks!

Comment: You have points and lines, do you want the last two points to be a different colour and the last two line segments, or just the last line segment? What's the colour of a line connecting two points of different colours?

Comment: I do not know of any magic way to automatically change the line color. If you need help you should ask a more specific question - ie. how do you want the lines broken up? Always by Wednesday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you need here, but it seems to me that you can do it easily enough in `ggplot2`.

[image: screenshot]

```
library(ggplot2)

dd <- data.frame(days = c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"),
                 things = c(1, 3, 6, 4, 9))

# set the levels of the factor so that 'days' sorts properly
dd$days <- factor(dd$days, levels = c('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri'))
# which days do we want to highlight?
days.highlight <- dd$days[4:5]

dd$highlight <- ifelse(dd$days %in% days.highlight, "red", "black")

ggplot(dd, aes(x = days, y = things, colour = highlight, group = 1)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    scale_colour_identity(dd$highlight)
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was asking for, I appreciate your time!

Comment: If you think this is the right answer then please click on the tick mark to the left of the answer. The tick will turn green, which shows that the question has been resolved by this answer. That's how Stack Overflow works. You might want to wait to see if somebody else offers another answer, of course.